# remote: true not working with safari when using inline svg

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, svg

I'm using [this](https://medium.com/@ramsaylanier/leveraging-ruby-on-rails-to-create-easy-to-use-inline-svg-icons-cde1cf209ea6#.x8z0ifnif) technique to embed svg inline.  It basically involves placing the svg inline code into a partial and rendering that partial at the top of the page.  In that page I have the following link_to block:

```
<%= link_to(resources_path, remote: true) do %>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#Icon-Res"/>
  </svg>
  <p>Resources</p>
<% end %>
```

This works fine in Chrome and FF.  In Safari if I click the text "Resources" it also works fine but if I click the icon itself a html response is rendered.

The ResourcesController index action is blank allowing rails to do its thing:

```
def index
end
```

Replacing the svg with an image by using the `image_tag` helper seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a version issue with Safari.  This issue occurs in Safari v6.2.8 (Mountain Lion) but works perfectly in v9.0.2